# Are microSD cards essentially the same inside the shell as a flash drive?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, sd-card, micro-sd-card, card-reader

I use a 64 GB Class 10+ microSD card with the computers' built-in card reader (sometimes requires a microSD to SD adapter), in place of a pen drive. This allows me to connect the card to devices without available USB ports.

Are microSD cards the same "under the hood" as a USB pen drive, or are there any advantages or disadvantages of using it compared to using a USB pen drive?

Comment: "This allows me to connect the card to devices without free or no USB ports" - How does the card reader connect to the devices? Anyway I don't see any disadvantages really except perhaps lower speeds and limited write cycles, but the same plagues USB sticks too (especially of the cheaper variety).

Comment: Basically, I can use it with a reader on most devices but a with an sd card adapter on others...

Comment: Besides the fact micro sd cards were not design to be used as a flash drive and doing will reduce their lifespans?

Comment: FWIW there are several SBCs (single board computers), e.g. Raspberry Pi & Wandboard, that employ a SDcard as its sole mass-storage R/W device.  So whatever disadvantages there may be, it would seem that they were not significant enough to deter its use.  Note that such SBCs access the SDcard through a MMC interface (rather than USB) which is a low-cost & simple interface (esp compared to USB or SATA).

Answer (score 2):

> Are microSD cards essentially the same inside the shell as a flash drive?

SD cards have their own communication standard and command set.  A microcontroller in the SD card implements these, with [possibly hackable firmware and vendor-specific commands](https://www.bunniestudios.com/blog/?p=3554).

A flash drive will implement the USB mass storage protocol in a microcontroller instead.  These also have [firmware that can be hacked/flashed/changed](http://www.myblog.bloggybloggy.com/usb-key-fix-mptools-11-05-2008/) but aren't implementing the same standard as SD cards.

Both USB and SD cards have a similar internal overall architecture (not internal architecture - you can't hack a USB microcontroller to work as an SD card microcontroller, for example), but different external interface and different protocols.

There's no practical difference from an end-user standpoint other than:

- SD cards are typically smaller (esp. microSD),
- full-size SD cards have a write-protect slider,
- USB 3.0 is faster than the latest SD card protocol but I believe no flash hardware can approach the max speed of USB 3.0.

On the hardware side ...

- The USB protocol requires more software support (due to enumeration, etc.) than the SD protocol.  This doesn't matter these days with powerful embedded CPUs being available for all sorts of portable devices and the prevalence of smartphones.
- Early SD card protocols were simple and cheap to implement in hardware, and you could even hack an [SD card reader into an old Linksys router without hardware SD card support.](http://www.yourwarrantyisvoid.com/2009/09/09/add-an-sd-card-slot-to-a-wrt54g-v2/) (you couldn't do that with USB unless the chipset supported it).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean advantages over standard USB jump drives, there is no major dis/advantage seeing as how they are, more or less, the same technology. The only caveat is read/write speed. However, the same argument can be said for both.

Also assuming that you connect your Micro SD's using either a SD Card card adapter (computers) or Micro USB to Micro SD (tablets/phones), you can make sure that the cable/adapter/port are of the same speed class. See the following for more information: [SD Card Speed Class](https://www.sdcard.org/developers/overview/speed_class/)

Answer (score -1):

Very few USB "flash-drives" have the feature on every standard SD card and microSD to SD holder: a READ ONLY switch. Whenever I use someone else's machine, I ALWAYS put the SD's *mechanical* switch into Read Only.

As for "speed" (and my USB-3 adapters to U3-Standard cards aren't "slow") security seems more important when I consider ... "BAD USB", which has NOT gone away. Many certified devices are vulnerable to this. How fast can YOUR USB "flash-drive" infect your network and compromise ALL your personal data? *"Convenience is the **opposite** of security (and privacy)."*

Comment: Thank you fixer1234! Edited Nov 9. Any better now?

Comment: Note that those mechanical switches are strictly a suggestion; the controller ultimately decides whether or not the card can be written to.

Comment: @DrWattsOn, much better as far as the rant.  However, I'm not familiar with the "bad USB" reference.  Are you referring to the fact that larger form-factor pendrives can contain malevolent custom circuitry that isn't practical to hide in SD cards?  That's true, but it isn't typically a problem with store-bought drives, which seems to be what the OP was referring to.  The issue of infecting a system/network from a "certified" device (what is that?) being possible from a USB device but not a card isn't clear.  Consider making the 2nd paragraph more explicit, maybe add a citation.

Comment: Neither my laptop nor my little USB card reader honor the write protect switch on SD cards.  That's very common these days.  Digital cameras for the most part still honor it, but it has to be remembered that it is merely a physical tab, it does not electronically prevent the card being written to.